# Removing rows that contain empty column without pandas

Tags: python, list

```
a_list = [ ["a", ""], ["b", "2"] ]
```

I have a list of lists as written above. Any suggestions on how to remove the row that contains an empty element (in this case the first list), without using `pandas`, so it returns:

```
a_list = [ ["b", "2"] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
a_list = [["a", ""], ["b", "2"]]

a_list = [l for l in a_list if "" not in l]
print(a_list)
```

Prints:

```py
[['b', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**To check at specific index too**

Here in your case you're check list[xx][1] index

**solution-1**

```
#Devil 
a_list = [["a", ""], ["b", "2"]]
a_list = [l for l in a_list if l[1] != ""]
print(a_list)
```

**solution 2**

Use another array and append the data init

```
new = []
for i in l:
    if i[1] != "":
        new.append(i)
print(new)
```